# Getting started with JOGL cube issue

Tags: java, jogl

I am new to JOGL but I am having trouble with the basics.  I think it is something to do with the camera angle but Im not sure.  I do not even know if all this code is even necessary or if I need more.

It makes the last drawn sides overlap the first ones (if the back was drawn after front, the back overlaps front).  It might have something to do with the depth or refreshing a variable after each frame.

The axes are supposed to go through the center of the cube but the cube gets cut off for some reason and does not display the sides correctly.  The coordinates at the top are the cameras "eye" position (floats relating to gluLookAt() first 3 parameters).  The cube is .5X.5X.5 centered around 0,0,0 (therefore extending .25 off each axis).

I cant post photos yet so here are my screenshots: http://www.flickr.com/photos/64158328@N02/sets/72157628882982925/

I am extending JFrame and implementing GLEventListener.  This is my OpenGL code from my constructor:

```
GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);
caps.setRedBits(8);
caps.setGreenBits(8);
caps.setBlueBits(8);
caps.setAlphaBits(8);
caps.setDoubleBuffered(false);
caps.setHardwareAccelerated(true);

GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);
canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
canvas.addKeyListener(this);
add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

anim = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
anim.setUpdateFPSFrames(10, null);
anim.start();
```

display method (along with the cube and axis code):

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
gl.glLoadIdentity();
GLU glu = new GLU();
glu.gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); // sets camera angle
gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

init method:

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

reshape method:

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: I think some of your display method code is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, I need to enable `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and I need to rotate the world around the camera using `glRotatef()` and `glTranslatef()` instead of using `gluLookAt()` to move the camera around the world.